"AttributeError: ArcSDESQLExecute: StreamExecute ArcSDE Extended error 900 ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement" error when running SQL query via ArcPy
I am trying to run a SQL query in ArcGIS Pro ArcPy and I am getting errors.  I have looked into the ArcSDESQLExecute sample query.
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/arcsdesqlexecute.htm
The code below is what I have written:
import arcpy

egdb = r'C:\Users\E149391\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\ElectricMeterLatLong\esripubp.sde'
egdb_conn = arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute(egdb)
sql = r'C:\Users\E149391\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\ElectricMeterLatLong\CustomerDataR.sql'
egdb_return = egdb_conn.execute(sql)

CustomerDataR.sql contains:
select b.servicepointglobalid as Svc_Glbl_ID, b.facilityid, 
a.addressline1, a.addresscitystate, a.meternumber, 
a.meterpointnumber, a.premise_num, a.SERVICE_PT_NUM, d.tmsnumber 
from refgis.customerdatar a, elepub.electricmeter b, 
elepub.transformer c, elepub.transformerunit d 
where a.meterpointnumber = b.meterpointnumber and 
a.premise_num = b.premisenumber and a.service_pt_num = b.servicepointnumber and 
b.transformerglobalid = c.globalid and 
c.facilityid = d.facilityid and a.statusmeter <> 'R' and 
a.statusmeterrecord = 2 and 
a.statename = 'MO'; 


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects\arcobjects.py", line
    44, in execute
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.Execute(*gp_fixargs(args)))
AttributeError: ArcSDESQLExecute: StreamExecute ArcSDE Extended error 900 ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement



You need to share the actual SQL statement for anyone to comment on how it might be invalid.  And, the execute method takes a string and not a path to a file.  The path to the file you are passing is not valid SQL.

Thanks, I will look into it.

select b.servicepointglobalid as Svc_Glbl_ID, b.facilityid, a.addressline1, a.addresscitystate, a.meternumber, a.meterpointnumber, a.premise_num, a.SERVICE_PT_NUM, d.tmsnumber
from refgis.customerdatar a, elepub.electricmeter b, elepub.transformer c, elepub.transformerunit d
where a.meterpointnumber = b.meterpointnumber and a.premise_num = b.premisenumber and a.service_pt_num = b.servicepointnumber
and b.transformerglobalid = c.globalid and c.facilityid = d.facilityid
and a.statusmeter <> 'R' and a.statusmeterrecord = 2 and a.statename = 'MO';

Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. Note that the semicolon is NOT part of the SQL statement (it's a SQL*Plus delimiter)

And the JOIN keyword was added to ANSI SQL in 1992. Using a FROM table list 32 years later is decidedly NOT best practice.

Suggest you accept the answer - https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

With the current code, this isn't a case of a SQL statement not being valid but of passing a non-SQL statement to a method expecting a SQL statement.  The error message returned will be the same in both cases, but troubleshooting is different.
According to ArcSDESQLExecute - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation:




Method
Explanation




execute (sql_statement)
Sends the SQL statement to the database via an ArcSDE connection. If execute is run outside of a transaction, a commit will automatically take place once the SQL DML (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE . . .) statement has been executed.




Looking at the current code:
import arcpy

egdb = r'C:\Users\E149391\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\ElectricMeterLatLong\esripubp.sde'
egdb_conn = arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute(egdb)
sql = r'C:\Users\E149391\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\ElectricMeterLatLong\CustomerDataR.sql'
egdb_return = egdb_conn.execute(sql)

The sql variable doesn't contain a SQL statement, it contains a filesystem path to a file containing a SQL statement.  To pass the SQL statement in the file to the execute command, the file has to be open and read first.
import arcpy

egdb = r'C:\Users\E149391\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\ElectricMeterLatLong\esripubp.sde'
egdb_conn = arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute(egdb)
sql = r'C:\Users\E149391\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\ElectricMeterLatLong\CustomerDataR.sql'
egdb_return = egdb_conn.execute(open(sql,'r').read())

Now whether the SQL statement itself is valid, that is another question.

I was able to get the script to work as follows:
I was able to meet with one of my coworkers and he walked me through the steps successfully of arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute(egdb).
import arcpy
egdb = r'C:\Users\E149391\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\ElectricMeterLatLong\esripubp.sde' 
egdb_conn = arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute(egdb) 
sql = ''' select b.servicepointglobalid as Svc_Glbl_ID, b.facilityid, a.addressline1, a.addresscitystate, a.meternumber, a.meterpointnumber, a.premise_num, a.SERVICE_PT_NUM, d.tmsnumber  
from refgis.customerdatar a, elepub.electricmeter b, elepub.transformer c, elepub.transformerunit d 
where a.meterpointnumber = b.meterpointnumber and a.premise_num = b.premisenumber and a.service_pt_num = b.servicepointnumber 
and b.transformerglobalid = c.globalid and c.facilityid = d.facilityid 
and a.statusmeter <> 'R' and a.statusmeterrecord = 2 and a.statename = 'MO' ''' 
egdb_return = egdb_conn.execute(sql)
for i in egdb_return:
   print('{}: {}'.format(*i))

